# Derivation of 1st law of thermodynamics using microcanonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

In the book *Statistical Physics of Particles* by M. Kardar, the author shows the connection between  the microcanonical ensemble and thermodynamics deriving the zeroth, 1st and 2nd laws. In the paragraph right before eq. $(4.7)$ it is stated the following:

> The first law: we next inquire about the variations of $S(E,\mathbf{x})$ with $\mathbf{x}$, by
> changing the coordinates reversibly by $\delta\mathbf{x}$. This results in doing work on the system by an amount $ \delta W = J \cdot \delta \mathbf{x}$, which changes the internal energy to
> $E +\mathbf{J}\cdot \delta \mathbf{x}$ The first-order change in entropy is given by
> $$\delta S(E, \mathbf{x}) = S(E +J\cdot \delta \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}+ \delta \mathbf{x}) - S(E, \mathbf{x}) = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} \mathbf{J} + \frac{\partial S}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \right)\delta \mathbf{x} \tag {4.8}$$
> This change will occur spontaneously, taking the system into a more probable
> state, unless the quantity in brackets is zero. Using Eq. $(4.7)$ ($\partial S/ \partial E = 1/T$), this allows us to
> identify the derivatives
> $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial x_i} |_{E, x_{j\ne i}} = - \frac{J_i}{T}.\tag{4.9}$$
> Having thus identified all variations of $S$, we have
> $$d S(E, \mathbf{x})= \frac{dE}{T} - \frac{\mathbf{J} \cdot d \mathbf{x}}{T} \implies dE = TdS + \mathbf{J} \cdot d \mathbf{x} $$
> allowing us to identify the heat input $\delta Q = TdS$.

What I don't understand is that if the author derived equation $(4.9)$ from the assumption that there's no heat (isolated system) and that the change $\delta \mathbf{x}$ is reversible, how can he just substitute this equation in the differential of entropy for a generic case (which allows flow of heat)?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this is the following: So, $S$ is a function of $E$ and $\mathbf x$. To get an expression for the differential of entropy $S$, one needs to know $\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} |_{\mathbf x}$ and $\frac{\partial S}{\partial x_i} |_{E, x_{j\ne i}}$. The former is $1/T$, and the latter is found out via the calculation shown.

Now, it does not matter how we calculate $\frac{\partial S}{\partial x_i} |_{E, x_{j\ne i}}$ since it is not something that depends on the path. It is simply the infinitesimal change in entropy (which is a state function) divided by an infinitesimal change in the coordinate $x_i$ (a state variable). Moreover, what we get after the calculation is indeed consistent with this fact as $- \frac{J_i}{T}$ is a state function.

I hope this makes it a little clear.